# Is there a way to recover unsaved Photoshop files?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, file-recovery

I was a complete dumbass who somehow managed to close photoshop without saving, not it crashing. Every ask I've come across is about what to do if it crashes, so, is there a way to recover an unsaved file from just accidentally closing everything?

Comment: No; it's not possible

Comment: Depending on the version you might consider checking into the autosave function for future protection of your work in progress.

Answer (score 1):

This article helped me to find some files, but not all
http://designpotato.com/how-to-recover-unsaved-files-in-adobe-photoshop-cs6/

In Brief it should be in: "C:\Users\YourUsername\Appdata\Roaming\Adobe\AdobePhotoshop CS6\Autorecover"

But it may help you find your files